# How do I update a time value back to NULL on a column with data type time(7)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, time

Let's say I key in 11:55 in a textbox and submit it over to the database.  But when it comes to editing part (update), how I make the value back to null?

This is my code so far:

```
DateTime meetingTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(txtMeetTime.Text, new string[] { "H:mm" },
          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
          System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
          out meetingTime);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateTime", meetingTime);
```

Comment: What have you tried? What issues have you encountered? Where's (any of) the code?

Comment: You can check whether textbox is left empty and perform needed action.

Comment: The error message would be something about converting.  Obviously you can't convert an empty field to datetime

Comment: please provide proper details.... this is not good question. sorry.

Comment: What do you mean proper details?  This is coherent.  All i want is to edit a time value back to _NULL_

I mentioned above that there are already time value stored and it's 11:55, I can change it to 19:20 but I can't change it to blank or null.  I don't need the time anymore.

This is my code to update the time to the database `DateTime meetingTime;  
DateTime.TryParseExact(txtMeetTime.Text, new string[] { "H:mm" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out meetingTime); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateTime", meetingTime);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
if(txtMeetingTime.Text.Length > 0)
{
    DateTime meetingTime;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(txtMeetTime.Text, new string[] { "H:mm" },
          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
          System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
          out meetingTime);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateTime", meetingTime);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@updateTime",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```